# t-sql subquery group by having linq ef

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Scenario:

- Module 1 has tags A B
- Module 2 has tags A B
- Module 3 has tag A
- Module 4 has tag B
- Module 5 has tags A B C

In table :

```
ModuleId TagId
1         A
1         B
2         A
2         B
3         A
4         B
5         A
5         B
5         C
```

Condition:

- I have list of TagId ex: List<> tagList = { A, B }
- I want all those TagIds falls under same ModuleId, other than the list of TagIds(that is tagList). So as result it should return TagId C.

TSQL statement -

```
select TagId 
from Table
where ModuleId in (
     select ModuleId 
     from Table
     where TagId in(A,B)
     group by ModuleId having count(ModuleId) = 2 )
and TagId not in (A,B)
```

LINQ statement -

```
List<int?> temp = (from t1 in context.Table
                            where tagList.Contains(t1.TagId)
                            group t1 by t1.ModuleId into grouped
                            where grouped.Count() == tagList.Count()
                            select grouped.Key).ToList();

           var result = (from t2 in context.Table
                    where temp.Contains(t2.ModuleId) && !tagList.Contains(t2.TagId)
                    select t2).Distinct().ToList();
```

So my question is-

- What should be the optimum approach for this scenario?
- If there is better approach then what would be the LINQ method syntax for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, you want items in your table that belong to modules that have items with *all* the tags in your tagList, but which themselves don't have the same tags as those in the tagList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simpler translation of your requirements, but it produces SQL that becomes far more complex as your tagList grows larger:

```
// Get items from the table
from t in context.Table
// ... that belong to modules
group t by t.ModuleId into moduleTags
// ... that have items for all the tags in the tagList
where tagList.All(tagId => moduleTags.Any(t => t.TagId == tagId))
from t in moduleTags
// ... but which themselves don't have the same tags as in the tagList.
where !tagList.Contains(t.TagId)
select t;
```

Starting from that, but leveraging your "Count == Count" trick, here's a fairly simple implementation that should scale better:

```
// Get items from the table
from t in context.Table
// ... that belong to modules
group t by t.ModuleId into moduleTags
// ... that have items for all the tags in the tagList
where moduleTags.Count(t => tagList.Contains(t.TagId)) == tagList.Count()
from t in moduleTags
// ... but which themselves don't have the same tags as in the tagList.
where !tagList.Contains(t.TagId)
select t;
```

This latter implementation, like your original SQL, assumes that both your table entries and your tagList have only distinct entries. Otherwise the Counts will be off.

Comment: Brilliant.. I will go for second LINQ statement.. Thanks